How to tell systemd that the service is "active (exited)"?
I have a console program that starts a background Thread with an infinite loop.
private static ManualResetEventSlim _quitProgramEvent = new();

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PosixSignalRegistration.Create(PosixSignal.SIGTERM, c => _quitProgramEvent.Set());

    Thread t = new(InfiniteLoop);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();

    _quitProgramEvent.Wait();
}

The program is executed as a systemd service.
[Unit]
Description=xreen
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/console-programm
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/dir
Type=oneshot

When I check the status via service xreen status it tells me that the service is still "activating".

Active: activating (start) since Sun 2024-04-07 10:39:54 CEST; 58min

How can I tell systemd that the service is already started and running.
How to change the status from the console programm in C#?

@downvoters, please tell why.

You can check the running processes by name to see if the process is running.  Can you see the process using Task Manager?

I found a solution here:
https://github.com/aremmell/net-core-systemd-service#2-notify-systemd-upon-successful-initialization
public static class Systemd
{
    [DllImport("libsystemd.so.0")]
    public static extern int sd_notify(int unset_environment, string state);
}

// Call it like this
Systemd.sd_notify(0, "READY=1");

As @user1686 mentioned you need to need to make the service Type=notify.


How can I tell systemd that the service is already started and running.

By not using Type=oneshot. This type is not meant for services that keep "running". It is specifically meant for short, one-shot tasks that are expected to complete before the job queue can continue.
If your service doesn't do the traditional "daemonization" (i.e. its initial process never exits), then it should be either Type=notify or Type=exec.
Type=notify is preferred as it still allows systemd to distinguish 'activating' and 'active' states; you send a READY=1 message over a Unix datagram socket to move the service to 'active'. (Type=exec doesn't have that, it always goes directly to 'active'.)
